# Accessing external application from Safari extension

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, safari-extension

Can i access an application which is running in the background from a browser extension?
My objective is to develop a browser extension which can access an application and execute some function which is performed by the application.

Thanks,

LS Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Safari extensions cannot access resources outside the browser apart from the local storage database.

Comment: Can they use URLs with schemes handled by external applications, though?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, but they can't retrieve results from an external app. `file://` URLs are specifically disallowed.

Comment: How can we use URLs with schemes? I'm new to this.

Comment: Well, if the external app defines a custom URL scheme (e.g. `twitter://` for the Twitter app) then your plug-in can tell Safari to open a link like `twitter://foo/bar` and the external app will handle it.